# Adding and dynamically changing the location of a Position Widget on top of a Google Map in a Flutter App

Tags: flutter, google-maps, asynchronous, dart

I want to add custom google map markers (as far as I am aware google map markers in flutter cannot have a widget as a child, therefore cannot be heavily customized). Code herein is a temporary workaround to solve the above problem.

***I want to add markers and widget card with one button and the position of the widget card to change when the GoogleMap onCameraIdle function is called (i.e. without the need for the yellow and green buttons)***

I would appreciate it if someone can help on this matter! Thank you in advance.

```
 import 'dart:io';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
 import 'utilities/constants.dart';
 

void main() =>
    runApp(MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: MapPage()));

class MapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MapPageState();
}

class MapPageState extends State<MapPage> {
  
  GoogleMapController _controller;
  List<Marker> _markers = [];

  double devicePixelRatio;
  LatLng _currentCenterPointMapCoordinate;
  List<Positioned> _positionedImageCardList = [];
  List<LatLng> _markersMapCoordinateList = [];
  List<ScreenCoordinate> _markerScreenCoordinateList = [];


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    devicePixelRatio =
        Platform.isAndroid ? MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio : 1.0;
  }
      
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CameraPosition initialLocation = CameraPosition(
        zoom: CAMERA_ZOOM,
        bearing: CAMERA_BEARING,
        tilt: CAMERA_TILT,
        target: SOURCE_LOCATION);

    SizeConfig().init(context);

    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Positioned.fill(
          child: GoogleMap(
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        compassEnabled: true,
        tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
        markers: Set.from(_markers),
              mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition: initialLocation,
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        onCameraIdle: () {
          _getCurrentCenterPointMapCoordinate();
          _updateScreenCoordinateList();
          _updatePositionedImagesList();
        },
      )),
      Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 40.0,
          height: 40.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.red,
              width: 2.0,
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              width: 6.0,
              height: 6.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        left: 10,
        top: 50,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          onPressed: () => _onPressMarkerAddButton(),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        left: 100,
        top: 50,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
          onPressed: () => _updateScreenCoordinateList(),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        left: 200,
        top: 50,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.upgrade),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          onPressed: () => _updatePositionedImagesList(),
        ),
      ),
      ...List.generate(
        _positionedImageCardList.length,
        (index) => _positionedImageCardList[index],
      ),
    ]));
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _controller = controller;
  }

  _onPressMarkerAddButton() async {
    _markersMapCoordinateList.add(_currentCenterPointMapCoordinate);

    _addMarkerToMap(_currentCenterPointMapCoordinate);
  }

  _getCurrentCenterPointMapCoordinate() {
    _controller
        .getLatLng(
      ScreenCoordinate(
        x: context.size.width * devicePixelRatio ~/ 2.0,
        y: context.size.height * devicePixelRatio ~/ 2.0,
      ),
    )
        .then((coordinates) {
      print("center position: " + coordinates.toString());

      _currentCenterPointMapCoordinate = coordinates;
    });
  }

  _updateScreenCoordinateList() {
    _markerScreenCoordinateList = [];

    _markersMapCoordinateList.forEach((element) async {
      ScreenCoordinate _currentElementScreenCoord =
          await _controller.getScreenCoordinate(element);

      _markerScreenCoordinateList.add(_currentElementScreenCoord);
    });
  }

  _updatePositionedImagesList() {
    _positionedImageCardList = [];

    _markerScreenCoordinateList.forEach((element) {
      setState(() {
        _positionedImageCardList.add(Positioned(
          top: element.y.toDouble(),
          left: element.x.toDouble(),
          child: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage('assets/friend1.jpg'),
            ),
          ),
        ));
      });
    });
  }

  _addMarkerToMap(LatLng tappedPoint) {
    _markers.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId('${_markers.length}'),
      position: tappedPoint,
    ));
  }
}

const double CAMERA_ZOOM = 13;
const double CAMERA_TILT = 0;
const double CAMERA_BEARING = 30;
const LatLng SOURCE_LOCATION = LatLng(42.7477863, -71.1699932);
```